# Setting mod_wsgi, django python version

Tags: django, linux, mod-wsgi

I'm having trouble setting up the correct python version for mod_wsgi / django setup.

After numerous bugs I think i'm nearing the end of this tedious setup... I'm trying to run a command from my manage.py file using `./manage.py collectstatic`

This is failing because it's trying to use the Python 2.4 version (I have 2.7 installed as well), I believe the version error only occurs when i manually try and run manage. My django.wsgi file inserts the python 2.7 dir into sys.path

Thanks for your help

Comment: Don't if this works for you but try :                         python2.7 manage.py collectstatic

Comment: In the future, I'd suggest using virtualenv so that you can make sure you're always using the same python version for one project.

Comment: I bet you're using CentOS? I'm also trying to get mod_wsgi working, under Python 2.6, but the version of CentOS I'm on, uses Python 2.4, alas. Even using `virtualenv` as Nick suggests, it's been a painful process (and I'm still not sure it's going to work).

Comment: After lots of debugging I got mod_wsgi to work on CentOS with Python 2.7 without conflicting with Python 2.4. Display Name had the correct solution for this particular question.
@John C if you get stuck I'd be interested in helping as it's a learning curve for me as well!

Comment: I'd love to discuss it, if you're interested - my VPS hosting company doesn't have much of a clue about anything non-standard. My email address is cyclops@speakeasy.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`python2.7 manage.py collectstatic` worked. Thanks to Display Name for the comment